# Select random N records from GraphQL query

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am building a simple quiz app that will allow a user to choose various categories and generate a 5 question quiz to test their knowledge. I have a long list of questions setup in AppSync accessible via GraphQL. However, as that list keeps growing, it doesn’t make sense for me to pull these to the client and randomly select there.

Does GraphQL support choosing random 5 from a query? Such that, serverside, I can select just 5 records at random?

```
 query listAll {
  listQuestions(filter: {
    topic: {
      contains: "chocolate"
    }
  }) {
    items {
      question
      answer
    }
  }
}
```

I have thought about other approaches such as randomly assigning each record a number and filtering on this, but this would not be random each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does GraphQL support choosing random 5 from a query?

Not directly, no.  Most of the more "interesting" things you might imagine doing in an SQL query, even simpler things like "return only the first 10 records" or "has a family name of 'Jones'", aren't directly supported in GraphQL.  You have to build this sort of thing out of the primitives it gives you.

> Such that, serverside, I can select just 5 records at random?

Most GraphQL server implementations support *resolver functions* which are arbitrary code called when a field value is requested.  You could write a schema like

```graphql
type Query {
  listQuestions(filter: QuestionFilter, random: Int): [Question!]!
}
```

and get access to the arguments in the resolver function.

It looks like [AppSync has its own resolver system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/configuring-resolvers.html).  It's not obvious to me from paging through the documentation that it supports a "pick *n* at random" method; it seems to be mostly designed as a facade around database storage, and most databases aren't optimized for this kind of query.

Answer (score 1):

David is right about writing this logic inside a resolver (as a GraphQL way).

If you are using AWS AppSync, you can use a Lambda resolver and attach it to the query, so you can write the logic to pick random values inside of the Lambda so it's part of the GraphQL response. This is one way of doing this.